# hide appendix frames (from presentation and bookmark)

Tags: beamer, bookmarks, appendix

I would like to hide the appendix section from bookmark, but I also like to get them available in case someone ask for. How can I do that?
I tried with `appendixnumberbeamer` package (and `\appendix`), but it just reset the number of page.

I followed a couple of links, but they didn't work. Any help would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent the sections in the appendix from creating bookmarks by modifying the `bookmarksdepth` before the start of the appendix:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=0}

\appendix

\section{in appendix}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! Do you know how to hide them from the presentation?

Comment: @Newbie If you want to be able to show the backup slides, they have to be in the presentation. If you really don't want them in there, you could move them to a second file and open this if you need something from the backup

Comment: Why does this solution work?

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 The `bookmarksdepth` sets how many sectioning levels will be shown in the bookmarks. With `0` none will be shown, which also means no sections will be shown.